# How to instantiate an Angular HttpClient?

Tags: angular, typescript

How do you instantiate an HttpClient in Angular 5? I need to instantiate it inside the constructor, but not in this line `constructor(private _Http: HttpClient)`.

Maybe something like this hypothetical example:

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
private _Http: HttpClient;
private _httpHandler: HttpHandler;
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    constructor() {
        this._Http = new HttpClient(_httpHandler);
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Why can't you do it in the constructor? That is how it's meant to be used. See the docs here: https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-request-for-json-data

Comment: What is the purpose of that ? Why standard way (dependency injection) does not work for you ?

Comment: why do you want to manually instantiate instead of relying on dependency injection?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo, depedency injection smells like bad programming to me, tbh. Sadly, it seems it's the only way to do it in Angular, as it's seen in the answers.

Comment: @osiris You clearly don't know how to smell code. DI is a well-known and mature Design Pattern. I advise you to study more about it.

Answer (score 14):

As previous answers stated, it's better to use dependency injection. That's being said, you can create instance manually like below

```js
const httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpXhrBackend({ 
    build: () => new XMLHttpRequest() 
}));
```

Comment: When I do this and try to use the `httpClient` I keep getting: `HttpErrorResponse: Http failure response for http://...: 0 Unknown Error`. Would love to know why.

Answer (score 4):

You should really use dependency injection, since it's very clean and easy:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
```

That's how the [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-request-for-json-data) and all Angular services are intended to be used. Read more about DI here: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection.

However, you can technically do it without DI, since it is just a class.

The issue with what you're currently doing with `this._Http = new HttpClient(_httpHandler);` is that the `HttpClient` requires an instance of an `HttpHandler`, but right now it's just getting a variable with no value called `_httpHandler` typed as an `HttpHandler`. You need to do this:

```
let _httpHandler = new HttpHandler();

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    constructor() {
        this._Http = new HttpClient(_httpHandler);
    }
}
```

That should get it to "work", but again I'd recommend taking another look at dependency injection.

UPDATE:

So as Jota. Toledo pointed out in the comments, you actually cannot instantiate an `HttpHandler` as it is an abstract class. See the source code here: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.1/packages/common/http/src/backend.ts#L12-L27.

So this just got a lot more complicated.

For `@Component`'s, there is a way to work with injectors directly that [the Angular team explicitly advises against](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#appendix-working-with-injectors-directly).

In your @Component metadata, provide the service you want to use directly (in the providers array), like so:

```
@Component({
 providers: [HttpClient]
}
export class MyComponent {}
```

And then you can inject the [`Injector`](https://angular.io/api/core/Injector) using *cough* Dependency Injection. And access your providers in the constructor like so:

```
constructor(private injector: Injector) {
  this._http = injector.get(HttpClient);
}
```

Although, I don't think this will work for your use case considering you show an `@Injectable` in your question, which doesn't have metadata per se. Second, you're already using dependency injection to get ahold of the `Injector` so you might as well just use DI for HttpClient.

It seems you can also still use the deprecated [`ReflectiveInjector`](https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable#example) to do this with an `@Injectable` class.

In conclusion, this is a wild goose chase and you should really use dependency injection. It is a fundamental concept in Angular and one of the things that makes the framework so useful. If for some reason you cannot use it, you may want to look at other options besides Angular.

Comment: HtttpHandler is an abstract class, cant be instantiated

Comment: You're right...editing my answer again to show a different way to do it. Thanks for the fact checking @Jota.Toledo -- I think this just goes to show that one should *really* juts use DI.